# Firefox Quantum : HTML files from internal storage (/usr) do not open

Tags: firefox, html, quantum

I use Firefox Quantum 65.0 in Ubuntu 18.10.

I recently installed TeXmaker. When I tried to open help files, I got following error from Firefox.

[image]

File path is:

[image]

I am able to open the same html file with text editor.

By the way, Firefox could open html files from /home folder.  However it could not access html files of /usr...

Please suggest about how I can open html files from /usr folder in Firefox.

Comment: How did you installed Firefox? Is it a Snap application? Please add outputs of `snap list | grep -i firefox`, `apt-cache policy firefox`, `which firefox`, `firefox --version` to the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that you have installed Firefox as a Snap. It is normal that it can't access the folders inside root-filesystem:

```
$ snap interfaces | grep firefox
:avahi-observe             firefox
:browser-support           firefox:browser-sandbox
:camera                    firefox
:cups-control              firefox
:desktop                   firefox
:desktop-legacy            firefox
:gsettings                 firefox
:home                      firefox
:network                   firefox,pulsemixer
:opengl                    firefox
:pulseaudio                firefox,pulsemixer
:screen-inhibit-control    firefox
:unity7                    firefox
:upower-observe            firefox
:x11                       firefox,pulsemixer
-                          firefox:network-observe
-                          firefox:removable-media
```

Consider to remove Snap with

```
sudo snap remove firefox
```

and install APT version

```
sudo apt install firefox
```

and visit local help page.

Comment: Is it just me or it's very dumb that 1/ Firefox snap version cannot open any file outside /home, thus preventing to read this kind of doc, AND to link any protocol handler to an app in /usr for example ; and 2/ that the snap version is the one appearing first in Ubuntu Software? Way to repell newcomers, I'm baffled.

Comment: For future visitors: since Ubuntu 22.04 the apt version is no longer available in the standard repositories. You can add the Mozilla PPA manually, but the snap version will reinstall itself unless you switch off unattended upgrades (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22).

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have an extra forward-slash in your file path.

Use **file:///usr/share/texmaker/usermanual_en.html**, it should work fine.

**Edit**- Just in case, here's the online help repo of TexMaker http://mcs.une.edu.au/doc/texmaker/usermanual_en.html

Comment: I tried your hint.  It did not work.

Comment: Ok try this.
Paste this to your firefox search bar `file:///usr/share/`. It should show you the directory tree. If it exists, then go to **texmaker** directory from there and open **usermanual_en.html**. Let me know if these dont work.

Comment: When I entered "file:///usr/share/", I got error "Access to the file was denied".

Comment: Go to terminal and open firefox with sudo, as `sudo firefox`. Then it should work.

Comment: `sudo firefox` does not start firefox due to error `mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied ....`

Comment: Are you using a guest account?

Comment: no. No guest accounts in my PC.

Comment: There are zero backslashes in the path.

Comment: Oh crap :)
Edited, thnx!

Comment: Running a web browser as root user or sudo is not a good idea. If that's considered a "solution", then something else is probably wrong (there was).