# Firefox can’t find the file at /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/en/index.html. or any html file opened from files

Tags: firefox, nautilus, 22.04, gimp

I have Gimp installed on 3 machines by means of apt install. On my new (secondhand) laptop,Gimp cant find the local help files (a common problem, with file:///usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/en/indexnap package, hence my install by apt). Even when I use nautilus to travel  to location /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/en any html file that I click on will produce a web page with:

File not found

```
Firefox can’t find the file at /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help/en/index.

    Check the file name for capitalisation or other typing errors.
    Check to see if the file was moved, renamed or deleted.File not found
```

as the content. None of the above conditions are true. On this particular machine (a Toshiba Satellite, running Ubuntu 22.04, I cannot open any html file via Firefox. On my other laptop and my desktop machines, I have no trouble doing this. I am at a loss for how to explain this situation. All help will be appreciated

Comment: May be related to: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114912/firefox-quantum-html-files-from-internal-storage-usr-do-not-open

Comment: @FedKad - It is related and I would remove the snap Firefox and install it by apt, if it were not for the assertion, that the snap would be automatically re-installed. It is not true that FF can't see anything outside home. It can open some stuff below /usr/share (e.g in docs) but other help files like libreoffice exhibit the same behaviour. FF under snap looks to be a MESS.

Comment: "f it were not for the assertion, that the snap would be automatically re-installed" It is possible not to have the snap automatically reinstalled. [This reference](https://fostips.com/ubuntu-21-10-two-firefox-remove-snap/) shows how - scroll down to `2. Set PPA Priority:` It works, I have this on my 22.04 instance using only the APT version of FF.